# Django Website If Search

Tags: python, django

I'm confuse with Python if
I make four imput text for search filter.
In Debug, I tried "x is not None" or " x != None "
But it can't work.
[Working fine Result while request have parameters]
[Working bad while request does not have any parameters][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMr0a.png)

```
def search(request):
good = request.GET.get("q2")
buyer = request.GET.get("q3")
StartTime = request.GET.get("SD")
EndTime = request.GET.get("ED")
context = {}
if good is not '' or buyer is not '':
    if good != '' and buyer != '':
        context = Dlyndx.objects.filter(
            Q(date__gt=StartTime),Q(date__lte=EndTime),
            Q(dlysale__btype__exact=buyer)&Q(dlysale__ptype__exact=good) |
            Q(dlybuy__btype__exact=buyer)&Q(dlybuy__ptype__exact=good))
        return render_to_response('search.html',{'context':context})
    elif good != '' and buyer == '':
        context = Dlyndx.objects.filter(
            Q(date__gt=StartTime),Q(date__lte=EndTime),
            Q(dlysale__ptype__exact=good) |
            Q(dlybuy__ptype__exact=good))
        return render_to_response('search.html',{'context':context})
    else:
        context = Dlyndx.objects.filter(
            Q(date__gt=StartTime),Q(date__lte=EndTime),
            Q(dlysale__btype__exact=buyer) |
            Q(dlybuy__btype__exact=buyer)).distinct()
        return render_to_response('search.html',{'context':context})
else:
    return render(request,"search.html")
```

Comment: I don't see any `None` in your code.

Comment: There is an optional argument to `request.GET.get()` that provides an alternative value, if the relevant first key is not found. By default, this is `None`. Since you're comparing to `''`, you could use .e.g. `request.GET.get("q2", "")` and set `good` to an empty string if `"q2`" is not found.

Comment: Since all your variables that you get from `request.GET.get()` are strings, it's more Pythonic to compare the variable by itself, since the emptry string (or `None`!) is a falsely value: `if not good or not buyer:` etc.

Comment: Thanks your very much! Yes. As your remind, It worked!